# Powershell counting occurrences of specific value combinations in pipe separated values in array

Tags: arrays, powershell

Sorry for the wording on the question as it's not brilliantly clear but this is what I'm trying to do.

I have an array containing 7 pipe separated values in each element. I need to count the combinations but not purely all unique combinations (there would be 896 of those).

Here is what the fields can be

- Field1 = 001 or 002
- Field2 = N or C
- Field3 = Y or N
- Field4 = Y or N
- Field5 = Y or N
- Field6 = C or not C
- Field7 = (L1 or blank) or (not L1 or blank) (i.e. a binary value as it is either one of those 2 or it isn't one of those 2)

If I've got the math correct, by switching them all to, effectively, a binary choice, I have reduced my combinations down to 128 as I can happily then split it into 2 subsets where field 2 is N or C and for the C ones I just need separate counts of the 2 possible values of Field 1 (i.e. 001 or 002) that would then reduce my further combinations down to 64 however, that's where I get stuck. For the two where field 2 is C I will just do something like,

`$count1 = ($data|Select-String "^001\|C" | Measure-Object).count`

So I would assume there is a way I could then do a a similar command to get the other counts, **I just don't know how to handle Field 6 and 7**.

When I know the values I can happily do the select but in the case of Field 6 I don't know how to do the "not C" and in the case of Field 7 where one of two values is one count and not one of those two values is the other then I'm struggling.

Comment: `|` is a special regex symbol, you need to escape it: `'^001\|C'`

Comment: Why not use `Group-Object`? `$data |Group {($_ -split '\|')[0]},{($_ -split '\|')[1]}`

Comment: I just spaced it out a little and emphasized the call to action.

Comment: Thanks Leon, I wanted that as a list but when I tried it kept telling me there was code not flagged as code. Didn't think of making it a bullet list.

Comment: Mathias, I've tried out group and while that does give me counts for each unique set of values, it will potentially give me 896 results therefore still giving me the issue of having 896 variables to deal with. I'm more used to bash shell than powershell so am not sure about more advanced uses of commands and unfortunately, despite having read what documentation I could find, I can't really see how Group-Object would help me.